# Is there an O(n) algorithm to generate a prefix-less array for an positive integer array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, integer, prefix

For array [4,3,5,1,2], 
we call prefix of 4 is NULL, prefix-less of 4 is 0;
        prefix of 3 is [4],  prefix-less of 3 is 0, because none in prefix is less than 3;
        prefix of 5 is [4,3],  prefix-less of 5 is 2, because 4 and 3 are both less than 5;
        prefix of 1 is [4,3,5], prefix-less of 1 is 0, because none in prefix is less than 1;
        prefix of 2 is [4,3,5,1], prefix-less of 2 is 1, because only 1 is less than 2

So for array [4, 3, 5, 1, 2], we get prefix-less arrary of [0,0, 2,0,1], 
Can we get an O(n) algorithm to get prefix-less array?

Comment: I asked this because I want to reap an O(n) to count inversion of a given array, even this array comes in stream.

Comment: Probably not. It looks like having a prefix-less array enables us to sort the original array in O(n) time.

Comment: @n.m.: How do we get sort the original in linear time with the prefix-less array? The approach I see to sorting using the prefix-less array is to insert each element at position p[i], but it isn't clear how this can be done in linear time.

Comment: @Nabb: I'm not sure it can be done in O(n), but it certainly can be done without comparing the elements at all. Sorting is O(n*log(n)) *comparisons*.

Comment: @n.m. - This argument is promising but tricky because it assumes 1) that the elements come from an unlimited domain, and 2) that the only primitive operations that we have are constant-branching (like comparison of one element against another which is 2-branching if we don't allow duplicates and perhaps 3-branching if we do) which gives you only 1 bit of information at a time).  Let's rule out bin sort and then ideally you should write this up as an answer.

Comment: @Weida - Did you mean "count inversions in a given array"?  (that would be clear enough) or "compute inversion of a given array"?  (then you'd have to explain what you mean by "inversion of an array" I guess).

Comment: @Weida - I think we'll need to know whether there is any practical limit on the integers in the array, like `10`, or `n`.  If they are allowed to be exponentially large (in the size of the input), which is the most general case, you'll probably receive a negative answer.

Comment: OK，count the inversion of a given array, say, an array of [4,2,3,1], the inversion pair of this array is [4,2], [4,3], [4,1], [2,1], [3,1] so the count inversion of array is 4.

Comment: @Nabb is right. To sort elements with prefix-less array you insert element into p[i] position. To do it in linear time you could use a list, for example, and then if you need array you can copy to it. So, for this example it will look like this: [4],[3,4],[3,4,5],[1,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]. So it cannot be built faster than O(n*log n).

Comment: If the only operation on the elements you can perform is comparison, than it is provable it cannot be done in less than O(nlogn), however if in constant time you can put the elements in correspondance with a fixed-width integer (for example because the elements are already fixed-width integers) than you can do it in O(n).  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done in `O(n)` for the same reasons a [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) requires `O(n log n)` comparisons. The number of possible prefix-less arrays is `n!` so you need at least `log2(n!)` bits of information to identify the correct prefix-less array. `log2(n!)` is `O(n log n)`, by [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Not exactly true. Comparison sorts require O(n log n), but there is no reason you need to do a comparison sort.  As an example, you can use Radix sort to sort integer arrays.  This is O(k*n) complexity.

Comment: @ShawnH I don't exactly say you have to use a comparison sort (or any sort for that matter) -- just that the same information theory logic applies. In radix sort, isn't k normally the number of digits, which is about log10(n), making it O(n log n)?

Comment: @xan: You can only make that implication if you add the constraint that the elements have to be distinct.  For example I can have an input array of one billion 1-digit elements.

Comment: True @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling. Thanks. There are fewer than n! possible outputs in that case, considerably fewer in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input elements are always fixed-width integers you can use a technique based on radix sort to achieve linear time:

- L is the input array
- X is the list of indexes of L in focus for current pass
- n is the bit we are currently working on
- Count is the number of 0 bits at bit n left of current location
- Y is the list of indexs of a subsequence of L for recursion
- P is a zero initialized array that is the output (the prefixless array)

In pseudo-code...

```
Def PrefixLess(L, X, n)
    if (n == 0)
       return;

    // setup prefix less for bit n
    Count = 0

    For I in 1 to |X|
        P(I) += Count
        If (L(X(I))[n] == 0)
            Count++;

    // go through subsequence with bit n-1 with bit(n) = 1
    Y = []
    For I in 1 to |X|
        If (L(X(I))[n] == 1)
            Y.append(X(I))

    PrefixLess(L, Y, n-1)

    // go through subsequence on bit n-1 where bit(n) = 0
    Y = []
    For I in 1 to |X|
        If (L(X(I))[n] == 0)
            Y.append(X(I))

    PrefixLess(L, Y, n-1)

    return P
```

and then execute:

```
PrefixLess(L, 1..|L|, 32)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, but double check the details.  Let's call an element in the original array a[i] and one in the prefix array as p[i] where i is the ith element of the respective arrays.

So, say we are at a[i] and we have already computed the value of p[i].  There are three possible cases.  If a[i] == a[i+1], then p[i] == p[i+1].  If a[i] < a[i+1], then p[i+1] >= p[i] + 1. This leaves us with the case where a[i] > a[i+1].   In this situation we know that p[i+1] >= p[i].

In the naïve case, we go back through the prefix and start counting items less than a[i].  However, we can do better than that. First, recognize that the minimum value for p[i] is 0 and the maximum is i.   Next look at the case of an index j, where i > j.  If a[i] >= a[j], then p[i] >= p[j].  If a[i] < a[j], then p[i] <= p[j] + j .  So, we can start going backwards through p updating the values for p[i]_min and p[i]_max.  If p[i]_min equals p[i]_max, then we have our solution.

Doing a back of the envelope analysis of the algorithm, it has O(n) best case performance.  This is the case where the list is already sorted. The worst case is where it is reversed sorted. Then the performance is O(n^2).  The average performance is going to be O(k*n) where k is how much one needs to backtrack.  My guess is for randomly distributed integers, k will be small.

I am also pretty sure there would be ways to optimize this algorithm for cases of partially sorted data.  I would look at [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) for some inspiration on how to do this. It uses run detection to detect partially sorted data.  So the basic idea for the algorithm would be to go through the list once and look for runs of data.  For ascending runs of data you are going to have the case where p[i+1] = p[i]+1.  For descending runs, p[i] = p_run[0] where p_run is the first element in the run.

Comment: It's not true that "If a[i] < a[i+1], then p[i+1] = p[i] + 1" as seen in the example a[1] < a[2] but p[2] = 2 and p[1] = 0.